# British sci fi TV series, mid-late 1960's - early 1970's; scientists try to block a door to the past

Tags: story-identification, tv

Think it was an early British Sci Fi serial (or perhaps a one-off) from the late 1960's (or more probably) early-mid 1960's. It may have been in black and white but possibly colour.

What I remember most is at the end where a group of scientists (at least one man and one woman) are trying to leave and block up a cave that seemed to be either a door way to the past (or to a hidden world).

The reason for this was a prehistoric monster (something along the lines of a Tyrannosaurus Rex?) was trying to escape.

Because it was live action, the monster's roar was worse than its bite.

I've checked both "Out of This World" and "Out of the Unknown" but it doesn't appear to be from either of these series. May have been an "Armchair Theatre" production? I thought it might have been "The Dummy" from Nigel Kneales' Beasts (1976) but it wasn't. However, the style of the episode suggested to me that what I am interested in was somewhat earlier than 1976.

Comment: I've cleaned up this post, and removed the old one as it was no-longer needed.

Comment: Something about this just has the feel of *Doctor Who* -- but I don't know the old episodes from Hartnell and Troughton (or even Pertwee) well enough to say for sure.

Comment: Definitely not Who (previous comments suggested "Carnival of Monsters"?, but can't find the original question)

Comment: Could this have been a movie that was shown on TV??

Comment: @theguest No, II don't think it was a movie, it definitely seemed like something with wobbly sets in it! Almost live action that was video taped rather than filmed.

Answer (score 9):

Although you say "Not Who" it is somewhat similar to the story [Doctor Who and the Silurians.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_and_the_Silurians)

Date - 1970,  several years earlier than *Beasts*.

The premise is that a race of intelligent creatures from Earth's past have been in suspended animation for millions of years. They are beginning to wake up, and want to take back their planet.

The protagonists are the Doctor and his assistant Liz Shaw, i.e.  "one man and one woman".

Their base is deep underground, accessed via a cave.

They have dinosaur-like creatures guarding their base, attacking people in the caves.

At the end,  the military blow up the cave, sealing them underground.

Comment: Yes, similar and a useful answer but not what I am thinking of, I don't recall any military in the story.